# $GF(3^3)$ as a set of roots of irreducible factors of degree 3 of $x^{27}-x$

Tags: galois-theory

Well, $GF(3^3)$ is a set of roots of $f=x^{27}-x \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

This polynomial has 8 irreducible factors of degree 3:

> $x^3+2x+1 \\x^3+2x+2\\ x^3+x^2+2\\ x^3+x^2+x+2\\ x^3+x^2+2x+1\\ x^3+2x^2+1\\ x^3+2x^2+x+1\\ x^3+2x^2+2x+2$

Let $g=x^3+2x+1$. Since $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $L=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(g)$ is a field.

Let $\alpha=x+(g)$. Then $\alpha$ is a root of $g \Rightarrow \alpha^3+2\alpha +1=0.$

$[\mathbb{Z}_3(\alpha):\mathbb{Z}]=3,\quad L=\{ a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2: a_i\in\mathbb{Z} \}=\{ \alpha^i:0\leq i\leq26 \}$

Now I want to find the remaining 2 roots of $g$ and also the roots of each of the remaining 7 polynomials. In this way we can conclude that if for each remaining $h\in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ of degree 3, if all roots of $h$ lie in $L$, then $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(h)\cong L$.

Since all of this is just a bunch of computations and it's long, may I ask someone who did this to share it here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for sharing the results rather than ideas.

Comment: If $g(x)$ is any of the listed cubics, and $\alpha$ is one of the zeros, the other two zeros are $\alpha^3$ and $\alpha^9$. This follows from Galois theory of the finite fields. The Frobenius automorphism in particular.

Comment: @Jyrki, right, but you don't need to bring Galois theory in at all, just verify that if $\alpha$ is a root of $g$ then so is $\alpha^3$.

Comment: True @lhf. That is not difficult at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+2x+1$, you can determine all powers of $\alpha$ using this information:
$\alpha^3+2\alpha+1=0$ means that $\alpha^3 = -2\alpha-1 = \alpha+2$.
Then $\alpha^4 = \alpha(\alpha+2) = \alpha^2+2\alpha$ and so on until $\alpha^{26}=1$.

Comment: How does that find the roots of $g$?